# Не работает rewrite при наличии директории

Tags: .htaccess

Eсли директория существует, то редирект в файле `.htaccess` не выполняется.

Например:

```
RewriteRule ^news/$ news.php [L]
```

не выполняется, если есть папка `news`.

Может, где-то в настройках apache проблема?

```
ServerName motor-vehicle.ru
SuexecUserGroup user user
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php5
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi/user/
<Directory /home/user/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "/home/user/public_html/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
LogLevel warn 
ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, полное содержимое файла. либо хотя бы все используемые в нём директивы `rewritecond` и `rewriterule`.

Comment: Это единственное правило
RewriteRule ^news/$ news.php [L]

Comment: значит, приведите текст хотя бы секции `virtualhost`, описывающей ваш сайт.

Comment: `код`<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName motor-vehicle.ru
 SuexecUserGroup user user
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
 php_admin_value engine off
 php_admin_value open_basedir /home/user/public_html
 Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php5
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi/user/
    <Directory /home/user/public_html>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
    </Directory>
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteLog "/home/user/public_html/rewrite.log"
 RewriteLogLevel 3
    LogLevel warn
 ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>`код`

Comment: извините, в комментариях форматированный текст, увы, нечитабелен. добавьте содержимое секции, пожалуйста, прямо в вопрос, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: нет, в конфигурации секции всё в порядке. я убедился на нескольких версиях *apache* — работает именно так, как и ожидается. единственная приходящая в голову гипотеза: у вас какая-то своебразная сборка/версия *http-сервера*. p.s. «неудачные» комментарии лучше удалять. это можно сделать, наведя «мышку» на комментарий и нажав появившийся в конце комментария «крестик».